# How to Move Column/(conky command) up 1 Line - Preferably with sed

Tags: linux, sed, conky

parts of my file look like this:

```
${goto 97}${exec sed -n '1p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 194}${exec sed -n '2p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 291}${exec sed -n '3p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 388}${exec sed -n '4p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 485}${exec sed -n '5p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 582}${exec sed -n '6p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 679}${exec sed -n '7p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 776}${exec sed -n '8p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
${goto 873}${exec sed -n '9p' $HOME/.config/conky/itl/raw2}#
```

and i want to move "${goto nn}" up 1 line, discarding the first one (or, optionally, move the first one to the last position)

edit: the numeric values after goto repeat in this way several times throughout the file. i want to change them all in the described way. also, the config file contains other stuff before and after.

since i'm just getting aquainted with sed i would like to solve it with sed but it's not a must as long as it can go into a linux shell script.

edit2: i hope it's not confusing that the config file contains sed commands, too.
that has nothing to do with the solution i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '$!N;s/^\(${goto [0-9]\+}\)\(.*\n\)\(${goto [0-9]\+}\)/\3\2\1/;P;D' file
```

- `$!N` for all but the last line append a newline and the following line to the pattern space
- `s/^\(${goto [0-9]\+}\)\(.*\n\)\(${goto [0-9]\+}\)/\3\2\1/` for two consecutive lines beginning with the expression `${goto [0-9]\+}` where `[0-9]\+` means one or more digits, make a note of these strings and the intervening string and swap them around.
- `P;D` print upto the first newline `\n` and then delete upto and including the newline. If the pattern space is not empty do not automatically read the next line but do begin a new cycle starting with the first command (which then appends a newline...).

Comment: thanks! that works!
would someone care to elaborate?
apart from 
    
    ${goto [0-9] 
i don't understand much.
also, why the round brackets ()?